# What is the best online Latin dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I'm familiar with perseus.tufts.edu and perseus.uchicago.edu and www.online-latin-dictionary.com. But I was curious to know what do you think is the best free online Latin dictionary?

Comment: Have you seen [this online dictionary question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79)?

Answer (score 1):

I think for vocab you've already got the link provided in the comment section, but on a side note, verbix.com is very useful for verb conjugation, and quite accurate (in my experience!)

Comment: You should add your answer to the [original question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why).